# How to apply style to CutyCapt

Tags: css, linux, raspberry-pi, headless-browser, cutycapt

How do I use the `--user-style-path` parameter with CutyCapt to apply a CSS style?  I'm using a command similar to this:

```
$ xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1280x720x24"  \
    CutyCapt --url=http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net \
    --out=/home/pi/image.png \
    --user-style-path=/home/pi/dark.css
```

dark.css contains `body { background-color: #888; }`

Currently I'm able to get an image, but it does not apply the style.  If I give it a path that doesn't exist, I don't seem to get any errors so I think I'm missing something here.
I've tried prefixing the path with `file://` and
I've also tried using `--user-style-string` wrapped with single or double quotes to no effect.

This code is running on a headless Pi using Linux.

Comment: I got it to work when I was using the Google home page as a target (had to use `! important`) but not with that particular page for some reason. CutyCapt's handling of user input definitely could use some work. Do you code?